# How to get randomized positions in certain area with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

i have a problem, with the node setup in Picture 2 I was able to get the fading hexagons around the controling empty in Picture 3. The grid in inside I get with the node setup in Picture 1. Now I try to get in the region around the empty a random distribution of the verts. I tried a lot but was not able to get a solution. Has some one an idea?

Thanks a lot!!

PS: Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.0 alpha

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 3.0 is still under development and something could not work as intended.

Comment: Yep, as Emir said, 3.0 may be having a bug. Try using 2.93 or below. I think u can save and export your project and open it in 2.93

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with this node tree:

[image]

Result:

[image]

and by the way: This is 3.0 alpha. I work a lot with 3.0 alpha and i cannot complain. It is pretty stable (of course it is alpha so it can crash - but from my experience, not very often) and its functionality is already awesome.